# Getting empty array while using %LIKE% in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I am fetching locations from the database. I have code in the controller like this:

```
public function getLocationsList(Request $request,$searchKey)
{
   $searchedLocations = Hotel::where('location', 'LIKE', "%$searchKey%")->get();
   return $searchedLocations;
}
```

I do not understand why `$searchedLocations` is empty when I have a record in the database.

I am using VueJs and axios to send requests.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: i think you forget to define location in your model

Comment: my column name in the database is `location`

Comment: in your model??

Comment: please show what `dd(Hotel::all())` gives and show your hotel model

Comment: @Sohel0415 doing this it is fetching all 4 records

Comment: please show what it gives and add your model with the questions

Comment: this is my db https://prnt.sc/j8wu54

Comment: @RakeshKohali please read my comment, that will be helpful

Comment: this is the result when i fetch all by doing This `Hotel::all()` https://prnt.sc/j8wv55

Comment: and what url you are trying?? i mean what you are passing as `$searchKey`?

Comment: This is my Route `Route::get('/getLocations/{searchKey}','HotelController@getLocationsList')->name('getLocations');`

Comment: please show the url you are trying like `www.domain.com/getLocations/condolin`

Comment: do you mean this? `http://localhost:8000/getLocations/can` ?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: in network tab `Request URL: http://localhost:8000/getLocations/%7Ban%7D` here i tried to search `an` so it would give `anjuna` from the database

Comment: do you have anything with this searchKey `%7Ban%7D`?

Comment: yes in the database i have a value `anjuna` but it is not getting that value  getting an empty array instead

Comment: please show what `dd($searchKey)` gives?

Comment: this dd($searchedLocations) https://prnt.sc/j8x43o and this is dd($searchKey) https://prnt.sc/j8x563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments ([dd($searchKey)](https://prnt.sc/j8x563)), I can see you are calling this URL

```
http://localhost:8000/getLocations/%7Ban%7D
```

or (same)

```
http://localhost:8000/getLocations/{an}
```

by calling the URL in this way you are actually including the curly brackets in the SQL statment:

```
Select * from location like "%{an}%"
```

this is why you are getting an empty result.

In order to solve your problem just change the URL **removing the brackets**:

```
http://localhost:8000/getLocations/an
```